# In Ionic 2, how do I create a custom directive that uses Ionic components?

Tags: javascript, ionic2

Creating a basic directive is simple:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<div>Hello!</div>'
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

This works as expected. However, if I want to use Ionic components in my directive things blow up.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<ion-list><ion-item>I am an item</ion-item></ion-list>'
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

The directive is rendered, but Ionic components are not transformed, and so wont look/work properly.

I can't find any examples on this. How should I do this?

Comment: If you feel the question is lacking somehow, please leave a comment instead of just downvoting.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got down voted. Excellent question and was exactly what I needed. +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-ionic-components-inside-custom-components-directives/39066):

> You have to import the Ionic components and register them as
>   'directives'

So my second example becomes:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {List, Item} from 'ionic/ionic';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    directives: [List, Item],
    template: '<ion-list><ion-item>I am an item</ion-item></ion-list>'
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Also you might want to just import all the directives `import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: you can also try ionic cli 'ionic g directive directive_name'.